# Two instances of a usercontrol

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, user-controls

As a newbie I'm trying to develop an application for autors. The workspace page holds a grid with two colums. The visibility of these columns (single or both) is controlled by radiobuttons. Each column holds an instance of WorkspaceUsercontrol.
The splitview pane of this usercontrol will hold chapter, scenes etc.  - the content will be filled with listview items of different type (text, images, html etc.) It should be possible to move a listview item from one instance to the other bei dragging, so changes of one instance should be reflected by the other. This is the code so far:

**EDIT**
To make it more comprehensible, I've build a new "stripped" project. I used Windows Template Studio (blank, basic MVVM).

MainPage.xaml

```
    <Page
    x:Class="Test.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:usercontrols="using:Test.Usercontrols"
    xmlns:toolkit="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid
        x:Name="ContentArea"
        Margin="{StaticResource MediumLeftRightMargin}">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="TitleRow" Height="48"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock
            x:Name="TitlePage"
            x:Uid="Main_Title"
            Style="{StaticResource PageTitleStyle}" />

        <Grid 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush}">
            <!--The SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush background represents where you should place your content. 
                Place your content here.-->
            <Grid
                Grid.Row="0"
                x:Name="WorkspaceGrid">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition
                        x:Name="Workspace1Column"
                        Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition
                        x:Name="WorkspaceSplitterColumn"
                        Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition
                        x:Name="Workspace2Column"
                        Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!--workspace 1-->
                <usercontrols:MainpageUsercontrol
                    x:Name="WorkspaceUC1"
                    Grid.Column="0"></usercontrols:MainpageUsercontrol>
                <!--Column Grid Splitter-->
                <toolkit:GridSplitter
                    x:Name="MainpageGridSplitter"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Width="11"
                    ResizeBehavior="BasedOnAlignment"
                    ResizeDirection="Auto"
                    Background="Gray"
                    Foreground="White"
                    FontSize="13">
                    <toolkit:GridSplitter.Element>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Text="&#xE784;"
                                Foreground="Black"
                                FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </toolkit:GridSplitter.Element>
                </toolkit:GridSplitter>
                <!--workspace 2-->
                <usercontrols:MainpageUsercontrol
                    x:Name="WorkspaceUC2"
                    Grid.Column="2"></usercontrols:MainpageUsercontrol>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using Test.ViewModels;

using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace Test.Views
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new MainViewModel();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

MainPageViewModel.cs

```
using System;

using Test.Helpers;

namespace Test.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : Observable
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

MainpageUsercontrol.xaml

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Test.Usercontrols.MainpageUsercontrol"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Test.Usercontrols"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:converter="using:Test.Converters"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <converter:NullableBoolToBoolConverter
            x:Key="NullableBoolToBoolConverter" />
        <Style
            x:Key="HamburgerButtonStyle"
            TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Setter
                Property="Content"
                Value="&#xE700;" />
            <Setter
                Property="FontFamily"
                Value="Segoe MDL2 Assets" />
            <Setter
                Property="FontSize"
                Value="20" />
            <Setter
                Property="MinHeight"
                Value="48" />
            <Setter
                Property="MinWidth"
                Value="48" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition
                Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition
                Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RelativePanel
            Grid.Row="0"
            Background="WhiteSmoke">
            <ToggleButton
                x:Name="HamburgerButton"
                Style="{StaticResource HamburgerButtonStyle}"
                IsThreeState="False"
                RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                IsChecked="{x:Bind WorkspaceSplitview.IsPaneOpen, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource NullableBoolToBoolConverter}}"></ToggleButton>
        </RelativePanel>
        <SplitView
            Grid.Row="1"
            x:Name="WorkspaceSplitview"
            IsPaneOpen="False">
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <Grid Background="LightGray">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition
                            Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Text="ToDo: Listview Navigation"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </SplitView.Pane>
            <SplitView.Content>
                <TextBox
                    Background="BlanchedAlmond"
                    Height="60"
                    Width="200"
                    Text="ToDo: Content"></TextBox>
            </SplitView.Content>
        </SplitView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainpageUsercontrol.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The User Control item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234236

namespace Test.Usercontrols
{
    public sealed partial class MainpageUsercontrol : UserControl
    {
        public MainpageUsercontrol()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

NullableBoolToBoolConverter

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace Test.Converters
{
    public class NullableBoolToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            bool? val = (bool?)value;
            return val.HasValue ? val.Value : false;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) => value;
    }
}
```

The problem: When i click the button of usercontrol **instance 1**, the splitview pane of this instance opens, but when I click on the button of **instance 2** afterwards, the splitview pane of **instance 1** closes. Why is this so?

I googled a lot about usercontrols in UWP, but I didn't find anything to deeply understand how they work:

- What is encapsulated (events, properties)?
- How do usercontrols communicate with the calling page?
- How do they communicate with each other?
- How does usercontrol.content works?

Hopefully I'm not the only one who is a little bit confused about usercontrols.

**Update**
The following image shows the live tree before clicking the button:
[image: Before]

and this shows the live tree when the split pane has openend:
[image: After]

Maybe this "popup root" is a hint to the solution?

Comment: I tested your above code snippet but cannot reproduce the issue you mentioned above. Could you please share a [mcve]?

Comment: I've edit code to make it more comprehensive. I hope, you can now reproduce the issue.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Accidently I found the solution: I added

> DisplayMode="Inline"

to my Splitview. I don't know why this works, but I will not complain. I will just gratefully accept;-)

Anyway: Is someone able to explain this kind of behaviour?